# What is the probability that the best N people come from China?

Tags: probability, distributions

Consider two countries competing in a game like chess. And suppose the abilities of all individuals have distributed according to Uniform[0, 1] distribution.

Say country `A` has population $P$ and country `B` has population $Q$.

Let $N$ be the number of people in country `A`, such that their abilities are all higher than the people in country `B`.

So $N$ must take the value of $0, 1, 2, ...., P$.

Is there a formula for $P(N > k)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to uniform randomness, that would be simply $$P(N>k)=P(N\geq k+1)=\frac{{P \choose k+1}}{P+Q\choose k+1}$$

It's choosing best $k+1$ people from population of $P$ people vs all possible choices, i.e. choose $k+1$ from $P+Q$ people.

Comment: I had figured out something similiar as well.